# how to troubleshoot: wcf application stops receive data via named pipe?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have UI WPF application that displays data received from WCF named pipe.
Aftwer a while (~30 minutes) data is frozen (but after restart everything ok).
No errors is displayed.
UI is responsible.
How to resolve the issue? Probably I should surrond entire application with "try/catch" and display any exceptions in messagebox?

Comment: Does the server respond to requests?

Comment: after restarting client everything works fine so I assume yes, server is alive

Comment: Have you tried wireshark? http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: no, but network is not elvoved. everything is local. can wireshark analyze local named pipes??

Answer (score 0):

By default, wcf is configured for short lived sessions. You have to set the ReceiveTimeout of your NetNamedPipeBinding to TimeSpan.MaxValue for this behaviour to disapear.
This should solve the issue, anyway it is a good idea to add a handler to your channel's Faulted, Closed, ... events to know what is happening. (you have to cast your channel to an ICommunicationObject). Because if anything goes wrong in wcf, your only solution is to create a new channel (it's not possible to go from Faulted or Closed state back to Open).

Comment: I think `set NetNamedPipeBinding to TimeSpan.MaxValue` will not resolve the issue because this belong only to "inactive" sessions. In my case session is pretty active.

Comment: how to `add a handler to your channel's Faulted, Closed, ... events `?

Comment: For the TimeSpan --> try it anyway, it doesn't hurt ;-) For the handler, my language is vb, but get, with a cast ( ) the ICommunicationObject associated with your channel add use MyICommunicationObject.Faulted += new System.EventHandler(this.MyFaultedHandler)   where MyFaultedHandler is a function with right signature : (Object sender, System.EventArgs e).